# VMware vmdk file restore

Tags: virtual-machine, osx-yosemite, vmware

Short story: machine (OS X Yosemite; VMware 10.0.1; host machine - Windows 7, i5, 8GB RAM) worked well, turned off well. Yesterday started machine - it began working very slowly. No other heavy process was launched, and nothing was changing at all, I can't understand why it working so slow. Couple of times I started machine and kill it by task manager.

**What I'm tried:**
 Tried to recover vmdk file by vdisk manager: `vmware-vdiskmanager -R "c:\[OS]\Yosemite\OS X Yosemite.vmdk"`. Output was: `VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parametr. Failed to read configuration file. No errors were found on the virtual disk`. Tried to check and repair disk c, virus scan.
 Today machine showed *new problem* - after turning on, it loading to quarter, then long pause, and exit without any messages or errors.I clambered a bunch of forums but found nothing.

**What I'm tried:**
 Tried to load machine in safe mode - but can't do it. Tried to create new machine using old vmdk.

***Main problem*** - machine has some important files for me, and I want get them.
I'm tried some programs for recover files (*PowerISO, SysTools VMware Recovery*) but none of them worked.

**What I'm asking for:** 
 Anybody knows means to restore vmdk, pulling files from it, or the way to make 100% sure that the disc is dead and nothing will not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the main problem. I Installed Paragon HFS+ on my PC, then mapped vmdk file and saw whole file system, restored important files.